# Map is not a function within React return

Tags: reactjs

Hi i stumbled on this strange situation.

So in the code example i indicated in comments where the problem is situated.

Within `useEffect` i get back the right data, an `array` of `objects`.
When i want to use the data within the `return`, i get the following errors:

1. shopFiltered.map is not a function
2. Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Thing that's quite odd though is that the log of `shopFiltered` in `useEffect` logs 3 times in the console: the first time it logs an `array` of objects, the second time it logs `1` (int) en the third time it logs `2` (int). What could be the explanation of this?

Thanks in advance

```
 export default () => {
 const [shopFiltered, setShopFiltered] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("My url which returns the data")
      .then((resp) => {
        resp.data.forEach((shop) => {
          Geocode.fromAddress(shop.acf.address).then(
            (response) => {
              let dis = getDistance(
                {
                  latitude: parseFloat(
                    response.results[0].geometry.location.lat
                  ),
                  longitude: parseFloat(
                    response.results[0].geometry.location.lng
                  ),
                },
                {
                  latitude: parseFloat(userCoords.lat),
                  longitude: parseFloat(userCoords.lng),
                }
              );
              if (dis / 1000 > 10) {
                setShopFiltered(shopFiltered.push(shop));
              }
            },
            (error) => {
              console.error(error);
            }
          );
        });
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(shopFiltered); // This gives me an array of objects, which is fine
  }, [shopFiltered]);



return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {!!shopFiltered && shopFiltered.map((data) => {
          console.log(data); // When i want to use the array and map over it here, i get the errors
        })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shopFiltered.push(shop)` doesn't return the array. it returns the pushed item itself.
so `setShopFiltered(shopFiltered.push(shop))` is not setting an array.

change that to `setShopFiltered(shopFiltered.concat(shop))`

Comment: Mahdi thanks for reply, i am now able to console.log data within return. However when i try to get the values out of the objects, my UI doesnt render anything. I double checked the keys in the objects so the problem should not be there. Got any idea?

Comment: {!!shopFiltered.length &&
              shopFiltered.map((data) => {
                <div> { data.acf.name } </div>
              })}

Comment: can you provide a sandbox so I can test your code in action? like jsfiddle of codingsandbox

Comment: ok i managed to get the data out with this syntax

Comment: {!!shopFiltered.length &&
              shopFiltered.map(function (item, i) {
                return (
                  <div key={i}>
                    <h3> {item.acf.address} </h3>
                  </div>
                );
              })}

Comment: The problem now is that i only get back one result, while there are 2 shop objects that should be returned. Maybe still something with the way how the objects are added to the array?

Comment: I need a live sandbox to probe

Comment: Ok Mahdi i found a solution fo the problem
This was what worked: `setTheArray(oldArray => [...oldArray, newElement]);`
Thanks again for your help!